# Flatten Array of tuples in Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Pair RDD of type

```
Array[((String, String), ((String, String, String, String, String), (Double, Double)))]
```

E.g:-

```
scala> joinWD.collect

res75: Array[((String, String), ((String, String, String, String, String), (Double, Double)))] = Array(((82010200-01,2008),((Acorn Lake,Washington,Lower St. Croix River,-92.97171054,45.01655642),(1.0413333177566528,0.04000000283122063))), 
((82010200-01,2008),((Acorn Lake,Washington,Lower St. Croix River,-92.97171054,45.01655642),(1.0413333177566528,0.04000000283122063)))]
```

I want to flatten it to A`rray[(String, String),String, String, String, String, String, Double, Double]`. The first tuple is key and all other elements are values.

How we can flatten it using Spark/Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a `flatten` method for tuples (unless you use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/flatten.scala)), so the `map` might not look very appetizing:

```
val myArr: Array[((String, String), ((String, String, String, String, String), (Double, Double)))] = Array(
  (("82010200-01", "2008"), (("Acorn Lake", "Washington", "Lower St. Croix River", "-92.97171054", "45.01655642"), (1.0413333177566528, 0.04000000283122063))),
  (("82010200-01", "2008"), (("Acorn Lake", "Washington", "Lower St. Croix River", "-92.97171054", "45.01655642"), (1.0413333177566528, 0.04000000283122063)))
)

myArr.map{ case (k, (u, v)) => (k, u._1, u._2, u._3, u._4, u._5, v._1, v._2) }

res1: Array[((String, String), String, String, String, String, String, Double, Double)] = Array(
  ((82010200-01, 2008), Acorn Lake, Washington, Lower St. Croix River, -92.97171054, 45.01655642, 1.0413333177566528, 0.04000000283122063),
  ((82010200-01, 2008), Acorn Lake, Washington, Lower St. Croix River, -92.97171054, 45.01655642, 1.0413333177566528, 0.04000000283122063)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, this really worked!!. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad that it helps.